# Drupal 7 with front-end in Spanish/English; Back-end in English only

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n

I installed Drupal in English and also installed the i18n and Locale modules for translation. I then enabled Spanish as a language and set it as default. My aim is to have the site default to Spanish (www.mysite.com/spanish-page), and to allow users to choose English if they wish (www.mysite.com/en/english-page).

My site is still defaulting to English... for example, in "admin/config/system/site-information", my Default front page setting is defaulting the the "en" (English) url prefix. I cannot delete that prefix on that page; it is listed in the non-editable text just in front of that field. Likewise, when I click the "Home" button on my admin menu, it takes me to "www.mysite.com/en" (the English home page) instead of "www.mysite.com" (which would be the Spanish home page). I'm sure it must be a default setting somewhere, but I cannot find it. Can anyone provide guidance on how to properly set up this type of language scenario?

Thanks!

Comment: If you switch to English version, All the page will be redirect to the www.yoursite.com/en/somepage include home page

Comment: I don't do a lot of multilingual work, but the admin_language module in the linked question works for me, which pretty much sounds like what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

I just found what I suppose is my "fix"... in "admin/config/regional/language/configure", I unchecked "Session", "User", and "Browser" in the "User interface text language detection" section, leaving only "URL" and "Default" checked. This seems to have fixed my issue.